# in qt whit c++ code don't show assembly code

Tags: c++, qt, assembly

I am using linux ubuntu , and I am using QTCreator 5.2 32 bit. I compile a program in debug mode, for debugging I use break point. when 1 compile it , it shows an assembly code and if I close assembly file and use F5 for run to next break point , it again shows assembly code,
how can I disable showing assembly mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop from showing assembly code while debugging, way out is just make sure you place break points in your code, so when you press resume button (F5 key in your case) it will come back to your code.

I have seen same behavior  in Visual Studio (Windows) and XCode (Mac).

Comment: I set break point in c++ code but when press F5 new tab was opened that has assembly code with some break point as I set in c++ code( if I use 2 break point in c++ , assembly code contains two breakpoint in the corresponding position.)

Comment: Can you share screenshots with your question.

Comment: here two picture from my code
http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/06/20/Snap2014062007h22m20s003.png
http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/06/20/Snap2014062007h20m19s001.png
and it is the test.pro file if needed
http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/06/20/Snap2014062007h22m09s002.png

Comment: @emranvfd Code seems to be normal C++ project not Qt project, I am right? Because if you want to start UI in Qt you do have some other content in main.

Comment: yes. I write normal c++ code and will add UI to it.

Comment: @emranvfd So code you should in screen shot also goes to assembly code directly?

Comment: yes. if I open the project and test.cpp file like in this picture
http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/06/20/Snap2014062016h10m51s002.png

and then start debugging (pressing F5) it goes to picture like this:
http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/06/20/Snap2014062016h09m59s001.png
and if close the assemble file and press F5 , again ot opens...

Comment: I think I have the same problem as in this link explains. but I don't understand what should I do!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985673/how-to-configure-qt-creator-to-show-c-codes-rather-than-disassembler